# US Robotics 56K USB Modem - Caller ID (Android)

Tags: java, android, at-command, modem, serial-communication

I am working on caller id in `android`. I have `us robotic` modem, and this modem is connected with the telephone line. I want to get caller id from this modem when phone is ringing.

Using **C#** some solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200921/how-to-get-caller-id-in-c) but not using android.

Comment: The accepted answer on the referenced question gives you the information you need to receive the number, so is your questions related to how to interface with the modem in Android software, how to write an Android app, how to interface the modem hardware to the Android device? This is too broad to answer and not enough information.

Comment: no my only question is how to receive that signal when phone will start ringing... any reference for android???